# Supervisord, Flask, Tornado (exit status 1; not expected)

Tags: python, supervisord, tornado, flask

Having some issues getting supervisor to run my tornado apps.

I have a REST API built with Flask, using Tornado to try and serve it.  Problem I am having is that when I try to run with supervisor it appears to be failing on import of other supporting python packages.

inf_api is the flask API.

Here is the script for the tornado

```
from influence_api import app
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8080, help="Port to listen on", type=int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Program section of the supervisord.conf (which I have tried several iterations of)

```
[program:tornado-8080]
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=USER=root,PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/
command=python /media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_server_nginx.py
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log
```

Ive tried playing around with how much is put in the environment and how much is put directly in the command. Including variations like.....

```
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
exitcodes=0,1,2
command=env PATH="/usr/bin/python" /media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_server_nginx.py --port=8081
command=/usr/bin/python /media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_nginx.py --port=8081
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log
```

Error output from supervisor

```
2014-02-25 16:55:24,917 INFO spawned: 'tornado-8080' with pid 3527
2014-02-25 16:55:25,156 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_server_nginx.py", line 11, in <module>

2014-02-25 16:55:25,157 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
    from inf_api import app

2014-02-25 16:55:25,157 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
  File "/media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_api.py", line 159, in <module>

2014-02-25 16:55:25,158 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
    mongo_ip = read_config('Database')['mongoip']

2014-02-25 16:55:25,158 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
  File "/media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_api.py", line 114, in read_config

2014-02-25 16:55:25,158 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
    options = config.options(section)

2014-02-25 16:55:25,159 DEBG 'tornado-8080' stderr output:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 279, in options
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Database'
.........
2014-02-25 20:29:26,924 INFO exited: tornado-8080 (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Running Tornado as is with or without SSL works just fine, as does the Flask API stand alone.  Ran supervisord with sudo and without....

As you can see I'm stumped - Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I sorted it out:
made sure all python files in the directory that I was using were executable

```
chmod +x <FILES>
```

Modified the Program portion of the supervisord file to look as follows

```
[program:inf_svr]
process_name=inf_svr%(process_num)s
directory=/media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/
environment=USER=root,PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/
command=python /media/sf_Projects/inf_api/inf_api/inf_server_nginx.py
startsecs=2
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
numprocs_start=8080
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log
```

Comment: the best practices would be to install your app in a python virtualenv (with all python dependencies installed in the virtualenv), then to reference the python executable of the virtualenv in your command= directive in the supervisor conf.